# Table View delegate methods are not getting called when using custom cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am using custom cell to display lists. Here in my code I found out that the tableview delegates are not getting called.

```
import UIKit

class MedicineViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var medcineCell: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var medInput: UITextField!

    var medicine:[String] = ["Medicine"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func medInsert(_ sender: UIButton) {

        insertMed()
    }

    func insertMed(){
        medicine.append(medInput.text!)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: medicine.count - 1, section: 0)
        medcineCell.beginUpdates()
        medcineCell.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        medcineCell.endUpdates()

        medInput.text = ""
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func savePresc(_ sender: UIButton) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    }

    extension MedicineViewController:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return medicine.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let med = medicine[indexPath.row]

        let cell = medcineCell.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MedicineCell")as! MedicineCell
        cell.medTitle.text = med

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: first you haven't call delegate and you didn't even call a protocol of tableviewDataSource which is used to populate tableview with data

Comment: Did you set medcineCell.delegate = self and medcineCell.dataSource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **viewDidLoad** add these two lines of code:

```
medcineCell.delegate = self
medcineCell.dataSource = self
```

and in **cellForRowAt** it's better to write code like this:

```
let cell = medcineCell.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MedicineCell", for: indexPath) as! MedicineCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out with the following points are properly configure or not

1. Set the `UITableView` delegate
2. Make correction in the following line

   ```
   let cell = **tableView**.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MedicineCell")as! MedicineCell
   ```
3. Add below function

   ```
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }
   ```

Hope this will help you! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

- Set Delegate and Datasource for TableView like

tblVw.dataSource = self

tblVw.delegate = self

or just set it using storyboard.

- once check the size of cell too in tableView "Size Inspector Tab"